# Расположение фигуры на одной строке с текстом

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как поставить **квадрат** на одной линией с текстом?

```css
/* Styles go here */

#square {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <hr>
  <div class="container" style="float: left;">
    1. Что такое ОЗУ?
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>1) Оперативно запоминающее устройство.</div>
    <div>2) Оперативно загружающееся устройство.</div>
    <br>

    <div>
      <div>
        <div>Номер правильного варианта задания <b>1</b>:</div>

        <p id="square"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Сейчас выводит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А я хочу чтобы было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как этого добиться? Я испробовал различные варианты, но ничего не получается.

Comment: А не лучше ли стилизовать `input` - элемент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/* Styles go here */

#square {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <hr>
  <div class="container" style="float: left;">
    1. Что такое ОЗУ?
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>1) Оперативно запоминающее устройство.</div>
    <div>2) Оперативно загружающееся устройство.</div>
    <br>

    <div>
      <div style="display:flex; align-items:center;">
        <div>Номер правильного варианта задания <b>1</b>:</div>

        <p id="square" ></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можна так, зделать.

```css
/* Styles go here */
.container{width:450px;}
#square {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-style: solid;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:18px;
}
.text{
width:70%;
display:inline-block;     
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <hr>
  <div class="container" style="float: left;">
    1. Что такое ОЗУ?
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>1) Оперативно запоминающее устройство.</div>
    <div>2) Оперативно загружающееся устройство.</div>
    <br>

    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="text">Номер правильного варианта задания <b>1</b>:</div>

        <p id="square"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

можна через display:flex;

Comment: или добавить для .text{float:left;} и для #square{float:left;}